# Disable polling in persistent way in solr replication

Tags: solr, replication

Is there a way to persistently disable polling in a slave SOLR instance?

If I call `http://slave_host:port/solr/replication?command=disablepoll`, polling stops but it restarts when core is reloaded.

In solrconfig.xml I didn't found any "disablePoll" parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to persistent this configuration.

if you are running a solr cluster, check solrconfig.xml on SLAVE nodes, there should be configuration like this

> *<str name="pollInterval">00:00:20</str>*

Above this line, the comment reads

> *"Interval in which the slave should poll master .Format is HH:mm:ss . **If this is absent** slave does not poll automatically. But a fetchindex can be triggered from the admin or the http API"*

So, comment out this configuration on SLAVE NODES to stop polling automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is this JIRA:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5640

You can vote to help the resolution of this JIRA